# CSV.foreach works with txt file but not CSV file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

When I import a CSV file in my Ruby on Rails app, it throws an error.  But when I convert it a .txt file, it works.

My model:

```
class Zip < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'csv'

  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      zip_hash = row.to_hash
      puts "==============\n\n"
      puts zip_hash // Just to confirm the hash was created
      // {"ZIP"=>"00501", "CBSA"=>"35004", "RES_RATIO"=>"0.000000000", "BUS_RATIO"=>"1.000000000", "OTH_RATIO"=>"0.000000000", "TOT_RATIO"=>"1.000000000"}
      puts "==============\n\n"
      Zip.create!(zip_hash)
    end
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
class ZipsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_zip, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy][![enter image description here][1]][1]
  def index
    @zips = Zip.all
  end

  def import
    Zip.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Success"
  end
end
```

When I upload a .csv file, I get

`ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'ZIP' for Zip.):`

This is my db file:

```
class CreateZips < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :zips do |t|
      t.integer :ZIP
      t.integer :CBSA
      t.decimal :RES_RATIO
      t.decimal :BUS_RATIO
      t.decimal :OTH_RATIO
      t.decimal :TOT_RATIO

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

DB Schema for `zips` table:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2018_06_19_024458) do
  create_table "zips", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "ZIP"
    t.integer "CBSA"
    t.decimal "RES_RATIO"
    t.decimal "BUS_RATIO"
    t.decimal "OTH_RATIO"
    t.decimal "TOT_RATIO"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add the result of `puts zip_hash`

Comment: what is the csv content, zip_hash needs to be in params format

Comment: Show a little more of error stack trace.

Comment: Can you also post DB schema for _zips_ table?

Comment: @Farid Please post more error logs and controller code as well so that we can dig more into the actual problem.

Comment: Updated post with requested info.